# expose internal web-site - mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, iis-10

I'm hosting locally a web-site (`http://gfd.us`) which I'd like to expose to internet. 
I have a second level domain name (from `NoIP` service) publicly available: `http://myname.ddns.net` which points to `Default Web Site` on my IIS server.

The problem here is that the internal web-site expects a second level domain name as well, i.e. `http://secondname.gfd.us`.

Right now to solve this problem I'm using the `mod_rewrite` module form IIS by binding to a specific port, i.e.

`mod_rewrite` rule parameters

1. Pattern - `(.*)`
2. Condition - `{SERVER_PORT} = 91`
3. Rewrite URL: `http://secondname.gfd.us/{R:1}`

Everything works as expected, when I open `http://myname.ddns.net:91` it will actually open the internal web-site `http://secondname.gfd.us`

What I don't like here is that if I need to use a different second level domain name for exposed web-site, i.e. `http://coolname.gfd.us`, then I need to have another rule bound to another port. I'd like to have this more dynamic.

I tried to change the Pattern to be like this `(.*)\gfd_(.*)` and the rewrite URL to be `http://{R:2}.gfd.us/{R:1}`, but it doesn't work as expected. When I open `http://myname.ddns.net:91/gfd_coolname` the site itself opens with needed second level domain name, but all of the CSS, JS and images files are pointing to wrong URLs as they are not being rewritten correctly.

Is this possible to achieve using `mod_rewrite` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should ditch `mod_rewrite` and configure many [Host-Headers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/08/02/an-area-of-confusion-with-host-header-ip-and-port-combinations-within-iis.aspx) for this website,

so along with `gfd.us` you should add configuration for the same IP and file location with host header `myname.ddns.net`

It also looks like you can [use wildcard since IIS10](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support) if you want to.